# Using Moq to verify a property changing multiple times

Tags: c#, moq

In the following example, how can I verify that the calling the `Start()` method resulted in the `Status` value changing to `Starting` then `Running`?

```
public class ServiceSettings 
{

}
public enum ServiceStatus 
{
    Stopped, 
    Stopping, 
    Starting, 
    Running
} 

public class SomeServiceHost
{
    public ServiceStatus Status => _serviceStatus;

    private ServiceStatus _serviceStatus = ServiceStatus.Stopped;
    private List<SomeActualService> _services;

    public SomeServiceHost(List<ServiceSettings> serviceSettings)
    {
        foreach(var settings in serviceSettings)
        {
            _services.Add(new SomeActualService(settings));
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _serviceStatus = ServiceStatus.Starting;

        foreach(SomeActualService service in _services)
        {
            service.Start();
        }

        _serviceStatus = ServiceStatus.Running;
    } 
}

public class SomeActualService 
{
    // I believe the context of this service class is irrelevant, as it's not accessible from the SomeServiceHost
    public SomeActualService(ServiceSettings settings)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a public auto property, and instead you're using a private backing field and a public field that returns the backing field's value?

Comment: Since it is a field on a concrete class, your only option to do just that is use `Microsoft.Fakes` but that is only available in full Framework.

However, if you show `// Do some other stuff` code, we may be able to come up with something

Comment: @MattU Not really any reason for this. I thought it would amount to the same thing in the context of this scenario? If changing it as you suggest makes it possible to test value changing twice, then I can certainly do that.

Comment: @zaitsman The code in `// Do some other stuff` is irrelevant. It's basic code that's already easily testable. I'm really just looking to verify this field being set twice.

Comment: @Klicker it is not about testability of that code. it is that if it provides hooks into the process you can assert before the hook, then assert after a hook...

Comment: @Klicker fields dont have getter/setter methods, so mocking frameworks like Moq/NSubstitute etc. have nothing to hook into.

Comment: @zaitsman I'll update the question and fill in the missing example code, but I dont think this will help at all - it just updates a bunch of private fields also. However, from what it sounds like, in order to verify this value being altered twice, I really need to have a publicly settable property?

Comment: You could implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-2.2) on your class and send an event when the value is updated. You could then hook that from your test.

Comment: @zaitsman unless you show us the code it is hard for me to tell you whether that is the only way or not

Comment: @SimplyGed that's one.. special way to do it right there... Imagine if this is console or web code?

Comment: @zaitsman Why would the project type matter? `INPC` is part of `netstandard1.0`+

Comment: What exactly is the `Status` property used for? If we knew that, it would be easier to understand what behavior would be valuable to be under test here

Comment: @Klicker well unfortunately i did get stuck in one place - Moq can't override non virtual methods and neither can i. Can you make `public void Start()` an interface member for `SomeActualService` or make it `virtual`? Or show the code for that :)) essentially we are looking for something to hook into to assert before and after the change..

Comment: @devNull good question! The `Status` is only used in `Start` and `Stop` methods, (although my oversimplified example code doesn't illustrate that), to make sure it can only be started/stopped under the right states, and for logging purposes.

Comment: @zaitsman I see where you're going with that. Yes, making `Start()` an interface member is probably a good shout, as a couple of classes (both the ServiceHost and SomeActualService) implement a method of the same signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current design of this code suffers from tight coupling to implementation concerns that make it untestable in isolation. The subject under test also appears to be violating Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and separation of Concerns (SoC) by manually creating the services to be started.

My recommendation would be to refactor the subject under test if possible

Some setup and the members involved before tackling the main goal.

Service abstraction and implementation

```
public interface IService {
    void Start();
}

public class SomeActualService : IService {

    public SomeActualService(ServiceSettings settings) {
        // ...
    }

    public void Start() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Service repository abstraction and implementation

```
public interface IServiceRepository {
    IEnumerable<IService> Get();
}

public class ServiceRepository : IServiceRepository {
    private readonly List<IService> services = new List<IService>();

    public ServiceFactory(List<ServiceSettings> serviceSettings) {
        foreach (var settings in serviceSettings) {
            services.Add(new SomeActualService(settings));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IService> Get() {
       return services;
    }
}
```

Refactored subject under test

```
public class SomeServiceHost {
    private readonly List<IService> services = new List<IService>();

    public SomeServiceHost(IServiceRepository repository) {
        services = repository.Get().ToList();
    }

    public ServiceStatus Status { get; private set; } = ServiceStatus.Stopped;

    public void Start() {
        Status = ServiceStatus.Starting;

        foreach (var service in services) {
            service.Start();
        }

        Status = ServiceStatus.Running;
    }
}
```

These abstractions now allow the subject under test to be unit tested in isolation without any undesirable behavior as it is now decoupled from implementation details.

All the implementations can be individually tested in isolation as well. making the code more flexible and maintainable.

For example, the following test verifies the expected status changes through the start process.

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeServiceHostTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Start_Services() {
        //Arrange
        var service = new Mock<IService>();

        var repository = Mock.Of<IServiceRepository>(_ => _.Get() == new[] { service.Object });

        var subject = new SomeServiceHost(repository);

        ServiceStatus before = subject.Status;
        ServiceStatus during = default(ServiceStatus);
        service.Setup(_ => _.Start()).Callback(() => during = subject.Status);

        //Act
        subject.Start();
        ServiceStatus after = subject.Status;

        //Assert
        before.Should().Be(ServiceStatus.Stopped);
        during.Should().Be(ServiceStatus.Starting);
        after.Should().Be(ServiceStatus.Running);

        service.Verify(_ => _.Start());//invoked at least once;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a huge improvement to what I had. I'm really grateful you took the time to refactor my example, as this not only gets me by today, but gives me a much better understanding of how to achieve a design that is testable in isolation, which will benefit me throughout my career. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Klicker glad to help. If you are not already familiar with SOLID principles, I highly suggest reading up on its practices. It is a nice foundation principle to be familiar with when dealing with OOP.

Answer (score -2):

If `Status` is a regular property such that `public ServiceStatus Status { get; set; }` then you can use `VerifySet`:

```c#
_someService.VerifySet(s => s.Status == ServiceStatus.Starting, Times.Once);
_someService.VerifySet(s => s.Status == ServiceStatus.Running, Times.Once);
```

Comment: Just FYI when creating the Mock for the service, use `{ CallBase = true }` to actually call your methods.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this seems like the kind of thing I'm after. However, in my case the `Status` would/should never be controlled from outside of the service, so I think making it publicly settable would really just be for the benefit of testing, which probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: @Klicker you can make it `internal` and then do `[InternalsVisibleTo()]`;

Comment: In that case you probably shouldn't be testing it anyhow, as it's an internal implementation detail of the class, in my opinion. Same reason you shouldn't try to test private methods. Instead, just validate that the `Status` is what you expect at the end of the test.

Comment: @MattU you should test every line of code someone writes. if anybody changes anything in the codebase, some test should fail. This goes for attributes, variable names, strings, etc.

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree. You don't need to test "every line of code", or even every unit of code. I definitely believe in thorough unit testing, but I don't try to test anything that's private. If I have that many things going on in "private" world, I'm probably doing something wrong.